# Import task scheduler xml file using cmd or powershell

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-scripting

I have exported task scheduler task in xml format and now i want to import it into different pc using cmd or powershell or any script only.

How can i import task scheduler xml file into task scheduler using cmd, powershell or any other script.
I'm studying computer programming and now im stuck on my project due to this reason so please help me with it.

Comment: We help you to fix an issue with your code here. We don't provide task based tutorials. Please perform this research yourself, then write some code, and try it, before posting it here for any help you may require with it.

Comment: @Compo i found i alternate so, please help me with that, i am going to run batch file(code=C:\file.exe) that will execute vbs(show msgbox) file. But whenever i use batch file to run this vbs file cmd with script stay open in background until i close msgbox. How can i hide that cmd in background

Comment: This site helps you to fix an issue with your code. In order to do that, use the [Edit] button, and submit it, making sure that you use the appropriate site formatting tools.